# Text box that is editable

Tags: php, html, forms, input, textbox

I have a text box that is populated by a form on my website. This text box is also editable and I'm having issues displaying the full text onto the text box from the form the user fills out. So, for example, if a user enters "hello there" and submits it, the text box will only display "hello" and not the full message.

my code:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM form";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row


   echo "<table>
   <tr>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
   </tr>";
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "<form action=findGroup.php method=post>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=text name=name value=" . $row['form_name'] . " </td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=text name=description value=" . $row['form_description'] . " </td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['form_id'] . " </td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=submit name=delete value=delete" . " </td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</form>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  }
```

Comment: Start by [escaping your values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: What's with the "</td>"? Your form is just wrong. Try  echo "<td>" ."<input type=text name=name value='" . $row['form_name'] . "' /></td>"; As you do not enclose your value in apostrophes, it is only picking up the first word it sees.

Comment: you have quite a few (HTML) syntax errors here. Did you look at your HTML source and developer console? You should also quote everything inside each input, those could have adverse effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is you do not enclose your values is apostrophes (''), so it only picks up the first word it sees.

Fix :

```
   echo "<form action=findGroup.php method=post>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=text name=name value='" . $row['form_name'] . "'/> </td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=text name=description value='" . $row['form_description'] . "'/> </td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=hidden name=hidden value='" . $row['form_id'] . "'/></td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=submit name=update value='update" . "'</> </td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=submit name=delete value='delete" . "'/></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Thank you, your fix worked also to an extent. When the user exceeds a certain amount of text the text box is not able to expand to fit all the text in now, would you possibly know a fix for this?

Comment: @Hasan That extra bit ^ wasn't part of the original question and constitutes as another question. If an answer solved the post itself, then the question should be marked as solved.

Answer (score 2):

- Add quotes to the html parameter value
- escape quotes in the form values
- end the <input with />

Make your lines for instance look like:

```
echo "<td><input type=text name=name value='" . addslashes($row['form_name']) . "'/></td>";
```

The rest of the lines similar.

Comment: Thank you, this did improve the results. I believe when the user exceeds a certain amount of text the text box is not able to expand to fit all the text in, would you possibly know a fix for this?

Comment: An input type='text' can hold 524288 characters, should be enough. What is your problem? That you cannot see all of the text? Then use <textarea name='name'>default text</textarea> instead

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/ Some tips on handling textarea, including sizing them.